# What is the SMD component (MRY marking)?

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount, schottky

I could not find the part number for this component (right arrows).

The component on the left is a Schottky diode, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [STM SM6T30CAY](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_STMicroelectronics-SM6T30CAY_C1973165.pdf) TVS diode.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/TVS_STMicroelectronics-SM6T30CAY_C1973165.html))

The part on the left is a [STM STPS15H100C-Y](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2004021607_STMicroelectronics-STPS15H100CBY-TR_C501050.pdf) Schottky rectifier, as you state in the question.